# ASP.Net - GridView server-side variable for each row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to add a hidden key field in a GridView that is not displayed to the user. I tried doing something like:

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="secretkey" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("secretkey") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But the hidden field still ends up visible as plain text in the html source. Is it possible to do something like this using server state?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I.e. what is the desired effect of using a hidden field?

Comment: I want to be able to attach a unique key to each row, for querying in the code-behind. For security reasons, I dont want to expose this key to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using datakeynames you can associate even multiple key to your rows. Check the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` would be the best place to store small data that you need across PostBacks but can't sent to the client.

You could put a Dictionary indexed by row identifier into session and use that to fetch your secret key.

Note that sessions are maintained across pages, so unless you are ok with the information being in memory till the user signs out(gets logged out eventually) you will have to delete it when done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes hidden field will be visible in html source, instead you should use  datakey  to use your secret key